# File exists by file name pattern

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, .net

I am using:

```
File.Exists(filepath)
```

I would like to swap this out for a pattern, because the first part of the filename changes.

For example: the file could be

```
01_peach.xml
02_peach.xml
03_peach.xml
```

How can I check if the file exists based on some kind of search pattern?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can do a directory list with a pattern to check for files

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*_peach.xml", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
if (files.Length > 0)
{
    //file exist
}
```

Answer (score 80):

If you're using .NET Framework 4 or above you could use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
bool exist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*_peach.xml").Any();
```

This could be more efficient than using `Directory.GetFiles` since you  avoid iterating trough the entire file list.

Comment: Your version of code make same thing, but hidden. No way to get all files matching pattern just from nothing.

Comment: @Kostadin: missed to answer this before... he doesn't  want to get all files matching a pattern, he wants to know if there is ANY

Comment: If you are stuck in 3.5 you can use bool exist = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*_peach.xml").Any();

Answer (score 6):

Get a list of all matching files using [System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx).

Also see Stack Overflow questions:

- [Is there a wildcard expansion option for .NET applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381366/is-there-a-wildcard-expansion-option-for-net-apps)
- [How do I check if a filename matches some wildcard pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652037/how-do-i-check-if-a-filename-matches-a-wildcard-pattern)

And many others...

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced searching against a specific pattern, it might be worth using file globbing which allows you to use search patterns like you would in a [*.gitignore* file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

See here: *[File globbing in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing)*

This allows you to add both inclusions & exclusions to your search.

Please see below the example code snippet from the Microsoft Source above:

```
Matcher matcher = new Matcher();
matcher.AddIncludePatterns(new[] { "*_peach.xml" });

IEnumerable<string> matchingFiles = matcher.GetResultsInFullPath(filepath);
```