# C#, using all files with the same extension in a folder

Tags: c#, file-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# file exists by file name pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199260/c-sharp-file-exists-by-file-name-pattern)

let's say I have a folder called documents, the documents folder consisting of pdfs, videos, texts, photos etc... I would like to do something with only .doc extensions. The only thing that I can think is actually creating a process that will use cmd.exe and use dir command in the directory, however I am looking for something more efficient. Any recommendations?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199260/c-sharp-file-exists-by-file-name-pattern

Comment: I did google but could not find it with my keywords. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're referring to the [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx):

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\documents").GetFiles().Where(x => x.Extension.ToLower() == ".doc")) {
    Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
}
```

Comment: this also causes .docx files to be shown

Comment: There is no way to filter `docx` out within the searchPattern filter. You have to manually do it. I will update my example.

Answer (score 0):

[Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx)

```
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.doc*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
    ...
}
```

If you want something more efficient:

> The good folks over at http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/ have
>   provided us with the source code.

Open the [VisualLogParser](http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/) solution in VS2010, ignore the prompt about debugging, after the solution loads, F5, set the combo-box to FS (FileSystem), paste in this query and press go.

```
SELECT
    ContentPath, [Days (Old)], FileName, [Creation Date Time]
    USING creationtime AS [Creation Date Time],
    TO_DATE([Creation Date Time]) AS Cdate,
    SUB(TO_LOCALTIME(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP()), Cdate) AS Days,
    DIV(TO_INT(Days),86400) As [Days (Old)],
    EXTRACT_PATH(TO_LOWERCASE(path)) AS ContentPath,
    TO_LOWERCASE(name) AS FileName
FROM 'c:\*.doc' 
WHERE
  (attributes NOT LIKE 'D%')
AND
  ([Days (Old)] >= TO_INT('0'))
ORDER BY [Creation Date Time] DESC
```