# How to check if a type of files exists in specific folder of a specific drive and return only the directory path within less time in C#

Tags: c#, directory, getfiles

I want to find all the document files from D drive . I have written the following code but it is too time consuming.
Also due to more time consumption in fetching the data it gives me exception.
In order to minimize the time ,I just want to check like this :

> even if one of the types of file exist within that folder
>   ->return the path of the folder

so that it doesn't need to check all the type of files within that same folder
example:-

if `C:\Program Files\Notepad++` 
has `readme.txt` ,and other text files. The moment it detects the first text file in this folder it must return : `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`

Code that I have used in my file

```
 List<string> mediaExtensions = new List<string>{"txt", "pdf"};
    List<string> filesFound = new List<string>();

    void DirSearch(string sDir) 
    {
       foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
       {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*")) 
        {
            if(mediaExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()))
               filesFound.Add(f);
        }
        DirSearch(d);
       }
    }
```

**Update1:**
Checking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access) 
did gave me an idea of recurssion and ignoring the files but not minimizing the time taken to search the files.

**Update2:-**
In the above code that I used `if(mediaExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()))` I dont get any value even if there exists files within the folder

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199260/file-exists-by-file-name-pattern) for this option: `bool exist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*_peach.xml").Any();` Using any should make it faster. Let us know if it does!

Comment: When at least one file is found, add the Directory into a list and use a break to stop searching in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

First Solution: (.Net 4.0)
This could speed things up a bit:

```
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(myBaseDirectory);
    return dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
           .AsParallel()
           .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
```

Second Solution: (.Net 3.5 and 4.0)
If that`s not helping check out the Faster Directory Enumerator based on a WinAPI function

Sources: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38959/A-Faster-Directory-Enumerator
Win Api Function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I can't use this EnumerateDirectories because I'm using .net 3.5,Is there any oher way @Marc Wittmann

Comment: Did you check the link for the FasterDirectory enumeration? As states this uses normal Windows API.. and it should be fast!
DirectoryInfo.GetFiles method: ~230ms |
    FastDirectoryEnumerator.GetFiles method: ~33ms

Comment: yes I checked them out ,and it seems to get faster result,but i have too many other things to add with it...also `EnumerateDirectories ` is accesssible only in net 4.0 @@Marc Wittmann

Comment: The class name is "FastDirectoryEnumerator", keep in mind it`s not the .Net one! The project itself is a 3.5 .Net Project and should be quiet easy to implement (not so much code because it uses the windows API). TheSource ocde is available at the link provided

Comment: +1 for the AsParallel. But what is important to mention, is that your code does not return the files in the topdirectory, they have to be searched in an extra call to EnumerateFiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Directory.GetFiles()` method to find files recursively. Check the options, you can adapt it to fit your needs without iterating the directories yourself:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.txt")) 
{
    // return ".txt file found in d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> mediaExtensions = new List<string>{"txt", "pdf"};
List<string> filesFound = new List<string>();

void DirSearch(string sDir) 
{
   foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
   {
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*")) 
    {
        if(mediaExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()))
           filesFound.Add(f);
           //you said you also need the path of the directory, add it from here
           break;
    }
    DirSearch(d);
   }
}
```

When you add the f argument, try to also add the d one from the outer foreach, your requirement was to add the folder with at least one file with the desired extension exists.

**EDIT 1**

When you encounter Documents and settings you have to access it using

```
var mydocumentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Comment: I get an unauthorized exception in executing the above code.cant those files/folder be skipped or store them in another folder path array to know that these files/folders had been given access denial???  @Olaru Mircea

Comment: I am curious, do you get the same result when running the application with admin right? Run the .exe with the option Run as administrator.

Comment: yes even doing like that i get exception denied for documents and settings in C:\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-denied check this post for the same Unauthorized issue.

Comment: check out this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqiwhej437xb5he/2%20%282%29.png?dl=0)

Comment: well unauthorized link wasn't that helpful @ Olaru Mircea

Comment: @TechBrkTru check my edit on the answer. You need to give special attention to that Documents and settings directory.

Comment: I may encounter like that with many other files later,so what could be done then??@ Olaru Mircea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80059/discussion-between-techbrktru-and-olaru-mircea).