# In C#, how can I find a file that matches this pattern?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a bunch of files that look like this where the first two characters in the file represent the month (the year can be assumed):

```
C:\folder\01_File.cvs
C:\folder\02_File.cvs
C:\folder\03_File.cvs
```

I have the following code in C#:

```
for (int i = 1;i < 13; i++)
{
    if (File.Exists("C:\folder\" + i.ToString("00") + "_File.cvs"))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This worked great, but now the file name are changing to show "MMDD" in the filename, so I am now getting something like this where the first four characters represent MMDD:

```
C:\folder\0122_File.cvs
C:\folder\0212_File.cvs
C:\folder\0311_File.cvs
```

Given I don't know (or really care about the day, but I can't change the file names, what is the best way to continue to have my code work by either getting the file using some wildcard regex search?

Comment: Does this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199275/115272 answer your question?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\folder", $"{i:00}??_File.cvs").Any()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file exists by file name pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199260/file-exists-by-file-name-pattern)

Comment: Re *"I have the following code in C# ... This worked great"*: It is not even syntactically correct. Is this a bogus question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a pattern search for all the files ending in `_File.cvs` and then do your logic on each of the files

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*_File.cvs", 
System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
if (files.Length > 0)
{
    //file exist
}
```

Comment: thank you but I still need a way to parse out the month from the file name