# Is there a opensource equivalent to the FileMatcher class in MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, command-line-arguments, wildcard-expansion

I'm building a command line tool which will need to resolve a set of files and folders based on one or more relative paths that contain single (*) wildcards, as well as any-depth-folder (**) wildcards.

Ideally, I would like a class similar that the one in MSBuild, so a usage pattern like:

```
FileMatcher matcher = new FileMatcher();
IList<string> files = matcher.Match("c:\data\**\bin\*.dll", "d:\da*\*.xml", "c:\temp\file1.xml")
```

Is there any open-source utility libraries out there which implement this functionality in .NET?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?